# What does this java output mean?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Arrys {
    private int[] nums;

    //Step 3
    public Arrys (int arrySize) {
        nums = new int[arrySize];
    }

    public int [] getNums (){
        return nums;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class TestArrys
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //Step 4
        Arrys arry = new Arrys(10);
        System.out.println("\nStep4 ");
        for(int index = 0; index < arry.getNums().length; index++) {
            System.out.print(arry.getNums());
        }
    }
}
```

It's incredibly simple, that is why I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. All I want is to display the value of the array.

This is what I get back. I am totally lost, there is nothing in my book that explains this nor does googling it help.

```
Step4 
[I@1ac88440[I@1ac88440[I@1ac88440[I@1ac88440[I@1ac88440[I@1ac88440[I@1ac88440[I@1ac88440[I@1ac88440[I@1ac88440[I@1ac88440
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to print the array *itself* out several times. This code:

```
for(int index = 0; index < arry.getNums().length; index++) {
    System.out.print(arry.getNums());
}
```

should (potentially) be this:

```
for(int index = 0; index < arry.getNums().length; index++) {
    // println instead of print to get one value per line
    // Note the [index] bit to get a single value
    System.out.println(arry.getNums()[index]);
}
```

Or rather more simply:

```
for (int value : arry.getNums()) {
   System.out.println(value);
}
```

When you call `toString()` on an array, it returns something like [I@1ac88440 where the [ indicates that it's an array, I indicates the array element type is int, and @xxxxxxxx is the address in memory. It's diagnostic, but not really helpful in most cases.

Use [`Arrays.toString`](http://www.uni-muenster.de/ZIV.BennoSueselbeck/java/jdk1.5.0_01/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])) to get a more useful representation.

Comment: You are so right. I glanced at the question, saw the `[l@1ac88440`, and thought I knew what the question was about -- but I was wrong.

Comment: Maybe I need to take up coffee.

Comment: Dang. I feel like such an Idiot right now! Thank you SO much!!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arry.getNums()));
```

instead of the loop.

By default, printing out an array will not give you a very useful string. To get the kind of output you're hoping for, you could loop through the array and print out each element yourself... or you could let [`java.util.Arrays`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) do the dirty work.

Answer (score 0):

It returns array:

```
public int [] getNums ()
```

This loop prints array reference getNums().length times...

```
for(int index = 0; index < arry.getNums().length; index++) {
    System.out.print(arry.getNums());
}
```

Try this:

```
int [] nums = arry.getNums();
for(int index = 0; index < nums.length; index++) {
    System.out.print(arry.nums[index]);
}
```